# Floating Boxes in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

A client recently reported a problem with their website.  They run Firefox as their sole browser, and all of a sudden, about a week ago, Firefox started displaying some floated boxes on their website in a strange manner (inserting empty space on second row of boxes).  I have since analysed the source and cannot see what is causing the problem - it displays correctly in all other browsers, and it did display correctly in Firefox until about a week ago.  No changes have been made to the source during that time.

Webkit Screenshot - http://postimg.org/image/jow77ae7b/

Firefox Screenshot - http://postimg.org/image/5txwotjs7/

This could well just be a case of needing a fresh set of eyes.  The CSS for the "gallery-box" class, which is applied to each of the boxes shown, is included below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-grid">
  <div class="gallery-box">
    <div class="gallery-box-content">
      Content of box...
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Repeat <div class="gallery-box"></div> -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery-box {
    float:    left;
    width:    33.33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:  inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help given, much appreciated!

Comment: I believe float forces an element to be a `block` so the `display: inline-block` would do nothing. But that is not your problem.

Comment: Can you show the HTML around the items too? Just the CSS really isn't enough.

Comment: This is a fair point.  I only added the `display: inline-block` tonight to see if it rectified the problem, after it was posted as a potential fix to a different floating problem in Firefox.  It didn't help, so I'll remove it again.

Comment: It's fine. I was just informing you. I know it's not actually affecting the situation.

Comment: The web page is http://onenoisemedia.co.uk/weddings.php if inspection with web tools would be better - I'll update the post with the HTML as well.  Cheers.

Comment: This is going to sound odd, but can you see if there are any hard returns in your code around that point. Just for kicks, put all that code on one line with no line breaks.

Comment: The code is generated by a PHP loop, so if it was a line break it would affect every box I'm guessing...

Comment: Damn. I've seen some strange things with line breaks. FYI IE has the issue too, but safari and chrome do not. I'm sort of at a loss. I suggest try making the width 33% and see if it's a rounding issue.

Comment: Changing to `width: 33%;` does not solve it unfortunately.

Comment: It's a kind of rounding issue, the first `.gallery-box` is 1px taller than the others, because the aspect ratio of the images isn't exactly the same (and you don't set an height, you let the adjust automatically). I'd suggest to remove the float and leave the `inline-block`, you'll have to remove every whitespace between the `div.gallery-box` tags, otherwise three images won't fix in a line (because there are also the whitespaces).

Comment: If that is the case, couldn't he also just set the height of the image and set the wrapping div to overflow hidden?

Comment: @Leeish Don't think that would play nicely with the responsive images.

Comment: The images are all the same size... per Firebug

Comment: The other option is to set the div.gallery-box background image as the image and set the `background-size: cover` and it would work responsive. You would need a polyfill for older IE versions.

Comment: But you are right, that 1px is most likely causing issues.

Comment: @Leeish Try to specify `heigth` to the first `img`, to the value you read on the `layout` tab. The reason is that Gecko makes small adjustments, less than one pixel. This is an example.

Comment: I've changed the back-end code to automatically resize the images to 640x360px.  Solved the problem.  Great eyes, @CarloCannas - add as an answer and I'll mark as solved.  Cheers for the help Leeish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a kind of rounding issue, the first `.gallery-box` is 1px taller than the others (even though the `img` element seems to have the same hight as the others), because the aspect ratio of the images isn't exactly the same (and you don't set an height).

I'd suggest to remove the float and leave the `inline-block`, you'll have to remove every whitespace between the `div.gallery-box` tags, otherwise three images won't fix in a line (because there are also the whitespaces).